# Get timestamp from Wikipedia API in Python

Tags: python, json, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get the timestamp from the Wikipedia-api and split it in format (y-m-d), but still can not find a way around to do that.

```
import requests

S = requests.Session()
URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?"
PARAMS = {
    'action':'query',
    'prop':'revisions',
    'rvlimit':'1',
    'rvprop':"timestamp|user|comment|content",
    'rvdir': 'newer',
    'format':'json',
    'titles': 'Brno'
}
R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
DATA = R.json()

PAGES = DATA["query"]["pages"]
print(PAGES)
for page in PAGES:
    print(page)
```

Here the output:

```
{'57575': {'pageid': 57575, 'ns': 0, 'title': 'Brno', 'revisions': [{'user': 'Jeronimo', 'timestamp': '2002-06-16T13:40:19Z', 'contentformat': 'text/x-wiki', 'contentmodel': 'wikitext', 'comment': '*', '*': "'''Brno''' (population 390,000, [[German language|German]]: ''Br&uuml;nn'') is the second largest city of the [[Czech Republic]], located in the southeast of the country, at the confluence of the [[Svitava]] and [[Svratka]] rivers.\r\n"}]}}
57575
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the loop will loop through multiple pages correctly as the code stands, you can change the for loop to:

```
for page in PAGES:
    date = PAGES[page]['revisions'][0]['timestamp']

    # Example date = 2002-06-16T13:40:19Z' Split on T to get the YYYY-MM-DD first
    formatted_date  = date.split("T")[0] 

    print(formatted_date)
```

Comment: thank you @Nebulous29 for your answer, but there is an error like this: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`, seems like it can not reach to timestamp.

Comment: Yeah that was a copy and paste error. I changed some variable names when I was testing it and I must have missed one. I've edited the answer - let me know how you go!